# Not able to select default email address from Entry source for Date based Entry event in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am using Date based Event as an entry source from my Journey Builder. In the journey settings, "Use email attribute from Entry Source" option is disabled. Is there a way I can use the email address from my Entry source DE where the date trigger is configured ?

[image]

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

So a Date base entry event is a different type of entry event from the Data Extension entry event, and subscribers need to exist within the "All Subs" list of within a population to be injected into the journey. So you must select an email from this source.

Depending on your use case you may be better off using a DE entry event and population it with a query of people to inject at the time